# combinatorial exercise in C++ seeing speed decrement vs VBA

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

just for recreation I thought I'd model a combinatorial problem with a monte carlo implementation. I did an implementation in VBA, and then as an exercise I thought I'd try and write it in C++ (am a complete novice) to check speed differences etc. Other than my not knowing advanced coding techniques/tricks, I had naively thought that as long as the model was faithfully transferred to C++ with mirroring functions / loops / variable types as far as possible etc that other than for minor tweaks the power of C++ would give me an immediate speed improvement as am running a lot of sims with lots of embedded sorting etc. Well, quite the opposite is occurring so, so  there must be something seriously wrong with the C++ implementation, which is about half as fast at best depending on parameters. They both converge to the same answer so am happy mathematically that they work.

**The problem:**

Suppose you have N days in which to allocate k exams randomly with, eg 2 exam slots per day (AM/PM). What is the probability that say 2 days are full exam days? I think I have a closed form for this which I believe for now, so anyway wanted to test with MC.

**Algorithm Heuristic:**

Quite simply, say we have 18 days, 6 exams, 2 slots a day, and we want to know the probability we'll have 2 full days.

(i)  simulate 6 uniforms U_i
(ii) allocate slots to the exams by randomly allocating them amongst remaining slots using the uniforms adjusting for slots already allotted. As as example if Exam 4 got allocated slot 4 in 34-slot space but 3 and 5 were already taken, then in 36-slot space Exam_4 would be allotted slot 6 (that would be the first free slot after rebasing). Have implemented this with some embedded sorting (in VB Bubblesort/quicksort has negligible diff, so far in C++ just using bubblesort). 
(iii) just convert the slots into days, then count the sims that hit the target.

Phew - that's just there for background. The spirit of this is not really to optimise the algorithm, just to help me understand what I've done wrong to make it so much slower when 'mirrored' in C++!!

**The Code!**

```
// monte carlo

#include "stdafx.h"
#include"AllocateSlots.h"
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, m;

    int days, exams, slotsperday, filledslotsperday, targetfulldays, filleddays;

    long sims, count, simctr;

    cout << "Days?: ";cin >> days;
    cout << "Exams?: ";cin >> exams;
    cout << "Slots Per Day?: ";cin >> slotsperday;
    cout << "Filled Slots?: ";cin >> filledslotsperday;
    cout << "Target Full Days?: ";cin >> targetfulldays;
    cout << "No. of sims?: ";cin >> sims;

    system("PAUSE");

    //timer
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();

    double randomvariate;

    //define intervals for remaining slots
    vector <double> interval(exams);

    int totalslots = (days * slotsperday);

    for (k = 1; k <= exams; k++)
    {
        interval[k-1] = 1 / (static_cast <double> (totalslots - k + 1));
    }

    vector <int> slots(exams);          //allocated slots 
    vector <int> previousslots(exams);  //previously allocated slots
    vector <int> slotdays(exams);       //days on which slots fall

    srand((int) time(0)); //generates seed on current system time
    count = 0;
    for (simctr = 1; simctr <= sims; simctr++)
    {
        vector<int> daycounts(days);        //initialised at 0

        for (i = 1; i <= exams;i++)
        {
            //rand() generates integers in [0.0,32767]
            randomvariate = (static_cast <double> (rand()+1))/ (static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX+1));
            j = 1;
            while (j <= totalslots - i + 1)
            {
                if (randomvariate < j*interval[i - 1]) break;
                j++;
            }

            slots[i - 1] = j;
        }

        for (i = 2; i <= exams;i++)
        {
            previousslots.resize(i - 1);
            for (m = 1; m <= i - 1; m++)
            {
                previousslots[m - 1] = slots[m - 1];
            }

            BubbleSort(previousslots);

            for (k = 1; k <= i - 1;k++)
            {
                if (slots[i - 1] >= previousslots[k - 1]) 
                { 
                    slots[i - 1]++ ;
                }
            }
        }

        //convert slots into days
        for (i = 1; i <= exams;i++)
        {
            slotdays[i - 1] = SlottoDays(slots[i - 1], slotsperday);
        }

        //calculate the filled days
        filleddays = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= days; j++)
        {
            for (k = 1; k <= exams; k++)
            {
                if (slotdays[k - 1] == j)
                {
                    daycounts[j - 1]++;
                }
            }

            if (daycounts[j - 1] == filledslotsperday)
            {
                filleddays++;
            }

        }

        //check if target is hit
        if (filleddays == targetfulldays)
        {
            count++;
        }

    }

    cout << count << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " s" << endl;
    //cout << (static_cast<double>(count)) / (static_cast<double>(sims));
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

And the 2 ancillary functions:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"AllocateSlots.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

//returns day for a given slot 
int SlottoDays(int &examslot, int &slotsperday)
{
    return((examslot % slotsperday == 0) ? examslot/ slotsperday: examslot/ slotsperday + 1);
}

//BubbleSort Algorithm
vector <int> BubbleSort(vector <int> &values)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int tmpSort;
    int N = values.size();

    for (i = 0; i < N;i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (values[i] > values[j])
            {
                tmpSort = values[j];
                values[j] = values[i];
                values[i] = tmpSort;
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

So there it is - like I say the algorithm is common to C++ and VBA, happy to post the VBA but in the first instance just wondered if there was glaringly thing glaringly obvious in the above. Pretty much first time have done this, used vectors etc etc, unaided, self 'taught' so have definitely screwed something up even though have managed to make it run by some miracle! Be very grateful for some words of wisdom - trying to teach myself C++ with exercises like this but what I really want to get to is speed (and mathematical accuracy of course!) for much larger projects.

Fyi in my example of 18 days, 6 exams, 2 slots per day, 2 days to get filled it should converge to about 3.77%, which it does with 1mm sims in 38s in VBA and 145s in the implementation above on my duocore 2.7G i7 4GB RAM laptop on x64 windows7.

Comment: you dont need to write your own sort, just `std::sort(values.begin(), values.end())` where ever you call `BubbleSort(values)`.

Comment: aah ok thanks will try that for sure hopefully that is much faster

Comment: I'll do that anyway - however again what I'm really interested in is why the code as is is so slow. I implemented exactly the same sort in VBA so am just perplexed! I had really expected C++ to kill it! hence the qn

Comment: `examslot/ slotsperday + 1` the `/` has higher precedence than `+` it will evaluate the division and add 1 is that your intention? if not  this should be `examslot/ (slotsperday + 1)`

Comment: If this code working, you should check out our sister site [CodeReview.se].

Comment: no i need it as is to allocate days correctly. i.e. slot 7 is on day 4 in  a 2-slot a day setup, as is slot 8, thx

Comment: @Code-Apprentice aah ok sorry I didn't know of that site

Comment: I guess it's just an efficiency speed thing - should I delete the question here do you think? I thought was ok to ask but yes it does actually work

Comment: What compiler and compilation flags are you using?  A frequent issue for "slow" C++ code is not optimizing.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm am using VS2017 pro, this was created as a x64 consol application. Will investigate compiler options hopefully easy to find - I don't know at the moment know what these are just started the project with whatever it's set to as default, like I say completely new to this!

Comment: If you just created the program and ran with default settings you are almost certainly running a `Debug` version of the program - all optimisation turned off and extra debug code generated.  Look for a white box with the word `Debug` in it under the menus and use the drop-down to change that word to `Release`.  Then rebuild the program and re-run your tests.

Comment: If you have any references/ tips for how I can optimise for this kind of project I'd be very grateful, definitely want to increase my background knowledge just to know what's good to read I guess, don't even know what a compiler flag is!

Comment: @FrankBoyne thanks very much will try that straight up!

Comment: Are you sure that `vector <int> BubbleSort(vector <int> &values)` should return _copy_ of sorted array?

Comment: @VictorIstomin so again am new to this and wanted to avoid copies, I had thought that I was passing vectors by reference, have I got this wrong?

Comment: @FrankBoyne - you have saved the day!!! from 145s down to 1.13s, phenomenal, thank you :) If you'd like to post as an answer in case helpful for anyone else who doesn't know their way around this will accept :)

Comment: @Mehness function declaration says you're returning `vector<int>`, so you're making a copy on `return values;` line. Although copy is not used, it will be made at least in debug build. I think, in this case it's better to return nothing (void).

Comment: understood thanks Victor will look into that

Comment: additionally, if you have 1 million sims, probably it's reasonable to create `vector<int> daycounts(days);` once before sims loop, and that just fill it with zeroes on each iteration with `std::fill(daycounts.begin(), daycounts.end(), 0):`. This will save ~2 million of syscalls on memory allocation/deallocation for you.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was wondering about that it looked inefficient to me just didn't know the easiest way to re-zero, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in comments it sounds like you may be running your program in `Debug` mode.  This turns off a number of optimisations and even generates some extra code.

To run in Release mode look for the `Solution Configurations` drop down in the Standard Tool Bar and use the drop down to change from `Debug` to `Release`.

[image: Visual Studio Standard Tool Bar Screenshot]

Then rebuild your Solution and rerun your tests.

To explore program performance further in Visual Studio you'll want to use the Performance Profiler tool.  There's a tutorial on using the Performance Profiler (including a video) on the Microsoft documentation site: [Profile application performance in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling).  There's also [Quickstart: First look at profiling tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour) and a whole bunch more: all under the [Profiling in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/index) section.

Comment: Thanks very much again, knew the C++ learning curve had to be worth it :) Will check out the references.